# I can't store more than 15 digits number in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

When I want to inset data, I got this error:

> Parameter value '15000000000000000/00' is out of range.

I searched the internet, and all answers are about datatype of table in SQL Server...

[image: SQL Table Information]

I'm sure I set it to more than '15 digits', and I still can't insert number.

this is save method:

```
public void Save(CompanySupervisory companySupervisory)
        {
            try
            {
                Insert(companySupervisory);
                SaveChange();
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new CustomException("error");
            }
        }
```

and viewModel class:

```
public long Id { get; set; }
public long CompanyId { get; set; }
public string CompanyTitle { get; set; }
public DateTime RegisterDate { get; set; }
public string RegisterDatePersian { get; set; }
public decimal SupervisoryCapital { get; set; }
```

Can anyone help me with this?

I've tried increasing Decimal datatype in SQL Server, and I've tried to find something about limitation in the code, but none of them worked for me.

Comment: From the SQL side you should have no problems inserting that value into a column using the `decimal(38,5)` data type. The _Parameter value_ portion of the error message suggests that this is actually an error in C#. Can you show us the C# code you're using to wrap the insert statement to SQL Server? Or how you are configuring the property in the model class?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) to see how you can improve your question.

Comment: Why is there a slash in the value?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Thank you for your help, I add my code to the question body.

Comment: Have you read about [Precision and Scale](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-properties?tabs=data-annotations%2Cwithout-nrt#precision-and-scale) yet?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I finally got the answer with your hints, that "Precision" data annotation only works with EF core and EF6, and since my project is a little old, I tried to add ".HasPrecision" method in the mapping class and it worked for me :) thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bigint` type. [int, bigint, smallint, and tinyint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

**bigint**

```
 range: -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807
```

Answer (score 0):

when we use decimal we should enter to number `DECIMAL(17,2)`
first is maximum number digit and the second is for maximum decimal  digit part
with `DECIMAL(17,2)` you can have 15 digit integer and 2 digit decimal
like this `1112223334445.12`

Comment: The first number is the **total number of digits** - before **AND** after the decimal point together. `Decimal(15,2)` means: 15 digits in **total** - thereof 2 after the decimal point (so therefore **13** before the decimal point)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16 your right . thank you